# Dynamically controlling sprite blit order with pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I'm currently writing a Tower Defence game. Everything works fine but there's a visual issue that's bugging me.

Basically, a sprite that has a lower `rect.y` and should be higher on the map to pass behind a slower mob with a higher `rect.y`, can be blitted *after* (and therefore in front of) the foreground sprite.

I could fix it, but not while keeping the random spread-out spawn points that I like.

Could anybody suggest anything to help? I omitted irrelevant code, so there's not much to sift through.

```
class Pokemon(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self, name, health, speed, attack, typeOf, typeOf2, level, order):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.order = order
        self.image = pygame.image.load('C:/Users/#/#/#/pygames/tower_defense/Distributable/images/POKEMON/%sright.png'%(name))

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        # X/Y axis locations
        self.rect.centerx = 0-self.rect.width - self.order*100
        self.rect.centery = random.randint(500, 540)
```

Then the creation block -

```
for e in range(numberOfEnemies):
    poke = random.randint(1, 2)
    if poke == 1:
        level = random.randint(2, 5)
        Pidgey = Pokemon('Pidgey', 15, 2, 5, 'Normal', 'Flying', level, e)
        enemies.append(Pidgey)
        enemy_sprites.add(Pidgey)
    else:
        level = random.randint(2, 4)
        Rattata = Pokemon('Rattata', 13, 3, 5, 'Normal', None, level, e)
        enemies.append(Rattata)
        enemy_sprites.add(Rattata)
    enemyNumber += 1
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you want to achieve, but it sounds like you could use a [LayeredUpdates](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) sprite group. I think the sprites need a `self._layer` attribute IIRC.

Comment: if you keep them on list then use `sort()/sorted()` with `key=` which use `rect.y` .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to control the layers of the sprites, you can use a [`LayeredUpdates`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.LayeredUpdates) sprite group. The sprites need a `self._layer` attribute or you can pass the layer when you `add` the sprite to the group, e.g.:

```
layered_group.add(sprite, layer=desired_layer)
```

When a sprite is moved, you can call the `change_layer` method of the sprite group:

```
layered_group.change_layer(sprite, sprite.rect.bottom)
```

However, if you have to update the layers of all sprites each frame, it would be more efficient to sort the sprites by their `rect.bottom` position, iterate over the list and blit them:

```
blit = screen.blit  # Local variable to improve the performance.
for sprite in sorted(all_sprites, key=lambda spr: spr.rect.bottom):
    blit(sprite.image, sprite.rect)
```

Comment: I looked into `layeredUpdates()` and it was what I needed. Thanks again!